# How to handle Time Durations stored in MySQL TIME field?

Tags: java, mysql, time, querydsl

I ran into an issue where my MySQL Table has a field that stores a UTC Time Offset. The field is of the type TIME. This is for Legacy reasons and I cannot change the column type to a better representation. MySQL, however, supports this. It allows the user to store a negative value in a time field to represent a negative time difference. I use querydsl for the Entity class generation and it mapped this field to a java.sql.Time object. Now I am facing an issue when there is a negative value in the DB. The java.sql.Time class converts any negative value into the time in the previous day. For example, if the value in the DB is -04:00:00, the Java object has the time 20:00:00. I was considering an option of converting this somehow to a Duration but then I ran into the issue where UTC timezone offsets overlap in certain regions.

Here, the negative offset goes down to -12:00:00 and the positive side goes up to +14:00:00. Now the problem is that I can't tell the difference between the values in the Java object for -12:00 and +12 because they both set to 12:00:00 in the java object. +12:00:00 to +14:00:00 also has overlapping values from both sides.

Any suggestion to handle this situation is highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: If you inspect the result of calling `getTime()` on your old-fashioned `java.sql.Time` object, you may be able to tell the difference. I wish I could tell you to get rid of the `Time` class, but for your particular setup I don’t know of a good alternative. I might consider `String` and do my own parsing into `java.time.Duration`.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. Yeah. That was my workaround for now. I read the value off of the ResultSet as a String without going through querydsl and converted it to a java.time.ZoneOffset instance, which works so far. I wanted to see if querudsl can handle this situation.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot help with QueryDSL.

## *java.time*

In *java.time*, represent an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) with [`java.time.ZoneOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html) class.

You might try either of these two approaches to see if they work.

### Parse MySQL `TIME` textually as `java.time.ZoneOffset`

Perhaps you could retrieve your unfortunate MySQL [`TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) values as text. Then parse as `ZoneOffset` objects.

```
String o = myResultSet.getString( … ) ;  // "-12:00:00" or "14:00:00", and such.
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = ZoneOffset.of( o ) ;
```

### Retrieve as `ZoneOffset`

I have no idea if this works, but you could try extracting the MySQL `TIME` as a `ZoneOffset` directly. Specify the desired Java class as an argument.

```
ZoneOffset zoneOffset = myResultSet.getObject( … , ZoneOffset.class ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Basil Bourque. This works well.